# Modify image after multiple Upload

Tags: php, forms, upload

Maybe it's an there are a lot of topics aout this argument, but I've read all of them and I can't find the solution(maybe it's very stupid and I can't see it).
I'm trying to modificy(if neccessary) and move the file I've uploaded to a certain dir. The problemi is that I cannot getimagesize info

Here the form

```
echo' <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="file" value="file_upload" />
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="upload_immagini" /><br />
<input type="hidden" value="',$id,'" name="id_prodotto" />
<input type="submit" value="Carica" />
</form>';
```

$id it's from another page and it works fine. I need to create the directory where I want to move the files after the resize

```
//UPLOAD
    if(isset($_POST['file']) and $_POST['file']=='file_upload'){
//Set $id
$id=(int)$_POST['id_prodotto'];
$dir='../media/images/prodotti/'.$id;

//Check if something was uploaded
if(!empty($_FILES['upload_immagini'])){
    $d=count($_FILES['upload_immagini']['name']);
    foreach((array)$_FILES['upload_immagini']['name'] as $i => $nome)
    {
        //Check the extension
        $estensione=explode(".", $_FILES['upload_immagini']['name'][$i]);

        if(!$estensione == 'png' || !$estensione == 'jpg' || !$estensione=='jpeg'){
            echo 'Il file ',$_FILES['upload_immagini']['name'][$i],' non è un\'immagine';
        }//If it's an image, I resize it
    else{
        //Info from the original one
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['upload_immagini']['tmp_name'][$i]);
            //Start Resize
                if($width > $height and $width > 900){
                    $img_width=900;//max wisth
                    $img_height=round(($height/$width)*$img_width);
                }elseif($height > $width and $height > 900){
                    $img_height=900;//max height
                    $img_width=round(($height/$width)*$img_height);
                }
                $img_ridimensionata=imagecreatetruecolor($img_width,$img_height);
                    if($estensione=='png'){
                        $source=imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['upload_immagini']['name'][$i]);
                    }else{
                        $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['upload_immagini']['name'][$i]);
                        }
                        //Check the directory existence
                        if (is_dir($dir)) {
                        echo 'Cartella già esistente';
                        } else {
                         mkdir($dir, 0777);
                        imagecopyresized($img_ridimensionata, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0,$img_width, $img_height, $width, $height);
                        imagepng($img_ridimensionata,$dir, 8);

                        imagedestroy($_FILES['upload_immagini']['name'][$i]);
                        }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting those errors:

```
"Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in /home/sakeh0/public_html/sportlife/admin/c/prodotti.php on line 128

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sakeh0/public_html/sportlife/admin/c/prodotti.php on line 132".
```

I think because in `getimagesize()` there's no value.

Comment: What are the actual values of $img_width and $img_height prior to the imagecreatetruecolor() call?

Comment: I guess you'll ave to fix the error on `line 128` :)

Comment: The valuse of $img_width and $img_height are estabilished by this part

 if($width > $height and $width > 900){[...]}

If the images is bigger then 900px, set $img_width or $img_height to 900px and than set the other one by round((height*width)/$mg_WidthOrHeight) according to the image parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the path and the name of the file. If  try to print
 
`$_FILES['upload_immagini']['tmp_name'][$i] 
$_FILES['upload_immagini']['name'][$i]`
 
I get '/' for the first and '0' for the second. If try to print

 `print_r($_FILES)`

 I get the name, the temporary path, the dimension, ecc...of the file I have uploaded.
Where's my mistake inside the foreach(I think it's there)?

Comment: I've solved deleting the multiple file uploa. I changed my mind